# Queue Message is not clearing in the ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have executed the following command:

```
$ artemis queue purge --name t24BROWSERQueue --user admin --password admin
```

It is cleared the messages, but the count will showing in the web console. How to clear in web console also?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Browse Queues" image you can see that there are still 27 messages in the queue. You can *also* see that there are 3 consumers. The messages that are still in the queue are almost certainly messages which have been dispatched to a consumer but have not yet been acknowledged. These messages are referred to as being "in delivery" and if you look at the "Delivering Count" on the `t24BROWSERQueue` I suspect you'll confirm this.

Furthermore, messages which are in delivery are not available to queue browsers which is why you don't see them on the "Browse Queue" page.

Comment: Yes, the message has been delivered, but there is currently no consumer. I have deleted the T24BROWSERQueue message count, yet 31 messages still appear in the browser. I don't know the reason; it's quite strange.

Is it possible to delete the log in Artemis? Perhaps that action will resolve the issue.

Comment: You've changed the underlying premise of the question at this point. You either need to completely change this question or ask a new one.

Comment: My question is the same as above. I want to remove the message that is showing in the browser image. I no longer have any consumers, and I want to set it to '0' message in the queue. For that, do I need to delete any log files in Artemis?

Comment: The fact that you now have 0 consumers on the queue means the underlying premise of the question has changed. My answer to your question was predicated on the existence of those consumers. If the consumers no longer exist then you need to update your question and clarify the exact circumstances of the issue you're currently facing.

Comment: Also, in your original question you had a queue named `t24BROWSERQueue` but now you say you've deleted it. Again, this is changing the underlying premise of the question. If you do not clearly and accurately describe your problem then folks will have a hard time helping you.

Comment: I deleted the messages from the queue 'T24BROWSERQueue' using '$ artemis queue purge --name t24BROWSERQueue --user admin --password admin,' but the message count still appears in the browser. Meanwhile, I don't have any running consumers. My question is, how do I clear the message count in the browser for 'T24BROWSERQueue'?

Comment: As noted previously, you're asking a _different question_ now since the premise has changed (i.e. there are no consumers). I recommend you create a new question.